# How do I prevent my Node js code from being stolen?

Tags: node.js, express

I need some advice. I am thinking of developing a new product using NodeJS and Express. This product should run on-premise mode. Because, Product will be information security product and will keep sensitive datas. I just want to guarantee that it takes a long time to be reversed.

So, How to protect my code from being stolen ? Or is NodeJS right choice ?

Are you have any tutorial or advice ?

Thanks and best regards..

Comment: It's unclear what specifically you're asking. If you're using NodeJS/Express the NodeJS code is on the *server*, not the client. You "prevent it from being stolen" by not letting people log in to the server, like any other server-side security concerns.

Comment: @DaveNewton Hi friend, I know nodeJS is a backend language. I am trying to ask that how to deploy nodeJS writen product on-premise mode ? Actually, This product will be sold under license to other companies. So, I'm concerned about my code being stolen.

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/631 etc. This is searchable on the web. The bottom line is that *anything* can be reverse-engineered (for now) and you need to do an ROI analysis to see if it's really worth it. It probably isn't.

Comment: Do not host this on-premise, sorry if you expected something else but truth is - if the client has your app, it doesn't matter it's javascript, .net or binary c++: everything can be reversed, it's just a matter of skills and time.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I already know anything can be reversed. But, this product will be information security product and will keep sensitive datas. So, companies do not want a cloud version. Because they don't even trust vendors. I should develop on-premise version. I just want to guarantee that it takes a long time to be reversed.

Comment: @Rasitaydin For a product so sensitive, I'm surprised you're not working out a deal where they *can* see the source code, to audit.

Answer (score 5):

If you are distributing the server software so that your customer can run the server themselves on premise, then you simply cannot protect your server source code.  If node.js can run it, then anyone at your customer's site who has physical access to the server can also see the source code.

With proper protections enabled by your customer, your server source code would not be available the the outside world, but you'd have to rely on your customer installing and securing things correctly for that to be the case.

You can obfuscate your source code before distributing it.  This type of obfuscation that renames all variables to give them meaningless names is not a real form of security at all, but it does make reverse engineering to understand what your code does more work (potentially deterring some people from putting in the extra work), but it does not prevent reverse engineering from a determined hacker.

If you have a relatively small number of secret sauce things you're trying to protect then a determined hacker can plow through the extra work of the obfuscation and still get to your algorithms.

In the end, the only real way to fully protect the internals of your work is not distribute your source code (no matter the language or environment) and to run a service and have the customer access your service.  Even with a fully compiled language (with no source code distribution) like C++, a determined hacker can still reverse engineer critical algorithms or credentials.

If the customer will only accept servers that they purchase and run on their premises, then my guess is that you're over-thinking this reverse engineering issue.  Anything you try do other than obfuscation is going to complicate your product and sale and make you sell significantly less while not really preventing the determined hacker anyway.

Answer (score 1):

## Plan A :

1. Prepare a self hosted Node and DB server.
2. Then expose API's for your secure product info with a unique/secure/hash api token.
3. Each vendor/company request a endpoint with token for consume secure product information that is bind a client app.
4. Then create a client application and it may be for X platform (Windows/Linux/android/iOS).
5. Prepare a license activation process for `one time one user`. If license activate then `send back to app client a api token for next request`.

> When user or company install this client app they must require a license key[api-token] and this license key you provide `one time one user or company`

#### So the original source code of this server is intake and no one can stolen this script & DB also.

Answer (score 0):

If your business model and customers support the idea that your company owns and operates the hardware on which your software runs (similar to how IBM and Oracle operates) and someone of your team can be on-premise at boot time (which isn’t always convenient), your could run Node on Linux and encrypt the data using [LUKS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup) which would make it very hard for an attacker (or corporate spy) to have access to the code without elaborate hacking.

You mentioned your services being sensitive. This approach would also help mitigate data breaches as the database would also be encrypted.

Depending on your needs for reliability, the hardware doesn’t need to be expensive. You can setup a cheap software [raid 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_1) which replicates the data and schedule encrypted backups on a small USB thump drive. If budget permits, you could also run this setup on server-grade computers which feature hardware raids, redundant power supplies and encrypted hardware [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) which would allow you to decrypt LUKS remotely (that being said, remote VNC isn’t as secure because [hardware key loggers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_keylogger) could be installed on the server without you knowing).

This hardware setup can cost only a few hundred dollars per client and it would make your service feel more "enterprise" and guarantee you code cannot be tampered with.

Comment: I don't understand what you are suggesting.  OP wants an on customer premise server.  You mention that customer doesn't own or operate the server.  How do you get all that?  If the customer doesn't own or operate the server, who does?

Comment: @jfriend00, when Oracle sells proprietary software to customers, it often ships on proprietary hardware that is operated by Oracle. This approach is a great way to protect source code. Why would anyone downvote this answer? It answers the questions which admittedly isn't code related. It should probably live on Server Fault more that Stack Overflow as everyone knows anyone with access to code can reverse engineer it, especially Node which isn’t compiled.

Comment: If you edit your answer to explain that you were suggesting that the OP sell proprietary and locked hardware that gets installed in the customer's premise (like the Oracle model), that would make your answer more understandable.  I don't think the OP was anticipating being in the hardware selling business so making that clear is important to explaining your answer.